# How to include multiple backslashes in Unix Korn Shell

Tags: unix

I have the following variables in Unix Korn Shell

```
host=nyc43ksj
qry_dir='\test\mydoc\mds'

fullpath="\\$host\$qry_dir"
echo "$fullpath"
```

When I execute the above, I get output such as `\nyc43ksj\qrydir`.
It looks like the backslashes are used as escape characters.

I tried changing `fullpath` as follows:

```
fullpath="\\$host\\$qry_dir"
echo "$fullpath"
```

This time I get `\nyc43ksj\test\mydoc\mds`.  However, the two backslashes at the beginning are not display as two backslashes. How can get the `fullpath` as `\\nyc43ksj\test\mydoc\mds` (two backslashes at the beginning).

Answer (score 0):

In a string, the `\` (backslash) character acts as an escape character (as you mention), and the second backslash instructs the shell to put in an actual backslash, as opposed to some special character.

If you want to have two actual backslash characters in the string in sequence, you will need to put `\\\\` in the string, so:

```
fullpath="\\\\$host\\$qry_dir"
```